# Java 8 Stream multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream

```
mylist.stream()
      .filter(m -> m.isokay() != null)
      .forEach(m -> m.dosomething()));
```

For this code, is it running on multiple threads?
If not, how can I do it? I want each `m.dosomething()` to run on seperate threads to speed this work up.

Comment: I think you are looking for [`parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--).

Comment: Fyi, `.parallelStream()` will make use of the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`.

Comment: Be aware that multithreading can, in many cases, slow your code down.  See e.g. [this page](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html) written by one of the authors of streams.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`parallelStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream--) to accomplish this.  Note that the documentation says that it is "possibly parallel", so there's a chance that you could return a non-parallel stream.  I would imagine those cases are rare, but be aware that it is in fact a limitation.

```
mylist.parallelStream()
      .filter(m -> m.isokay() != null)
      .forEach(m -> m.dosomething()));
```

Comment: Oracle doc specifies "When a stream executes in parallel, the Java runtime partitions the stream into multiple substreams". In this case, "possibly parallel" probably means that you get a sequential stream if it just doesn't make sense to make a parallel one (say if the stream is only one item in size, or threads are currently in short supply)